# If $U$ is an unitary operator from $L^2(\Omega_1)$ to $L^2(\Omega_2)$, then $U$ commutes with the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian, linear-pde

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $\Omega_i\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $$P_i\varphi:=-\Delta\varphi\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega_1);$$
- $U:L^2(\Omega_1)\to L^2(\Omega_2)$ be an isometry$^1$

> How can we show that $UP_1=P_2U$ in the weak sense?

Let $f_1\in L^2(\Omega_1)$. We need to show that $f_2:=Uf_1\in L^2(\Omega_2)$ is a weak solution of $P_2f_2=g_2:=UP_1f_1\in ^2(\Omega_2)$, i.e. $$\langle f_2,P_2\varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega_2)}=\langle g_2,\varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega_2)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega_2)\tag1.$$

> How can we do that?

Even when I impose the stronger assumption of $U$ being an unitary linear operator (from which we know that $U$ is bijective and $U^\ast=U^{-1}$), I only obtain $$\langle f_2,P_2\varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega_2)}=\langle f_1,U^{-1}P_2\varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega_1)}\tag2$$ and don't know how to proceed from there ...

**EDIT**: I've read that "it is very easy to verify that if $Ω_1$ and $Ω_2$ are isometric, then the Dirichlet eigenvalues of the laplacian on $Ω_1$ and $Ω_2$ coincide" ... If the assertion, as stated in my question, is not true, how can that claim be stated and proven correctly?

---

$^1$ I'm not sure, but maybe we need to assume that $U$ is linear and surjective as well. Phrased differently, $U$ is then an unitary linear operator from $L^2(\Omega_1)$ to $L^2(\Omega_2)$.

Comment: Why do you think $U$ should commute with the Laplacian?

Comment: This is definitely not true.  For instance, take two unit eigenvectors of $P$ with different eigenvalues, and pick a $U$ which interchanges them.

Comment: @JackyChong I thought it would be true, since it is what I've understood that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4023875/47771) (in the last bullet point) would claim. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: @NateEldredge Please take note of my comment above.

Comment: As the answer says, there are always lots of unitary maps between two $L^2$ spaces (as they're both separable Hilbert spaces).  The vast majority do not commute with the Laplacian; possibly none at all do.  If there is one that does, *then* the two Laplacians must have the same spectra.  But as the contrapositive, if for example they have different spectra, then there are still lots of unitary maps but none of them can commute with the Laplacians.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for the explanation. Does the claim hold for the special unitary map $U$ constructed from $\iota$ in that question? In a lecture note I've read that "it is very easy to verify that if $\Omega$ and $\tilde\Omega$ are isometric, then the Dirichlet eigenvalues of the laplacian on $\Omega$ and $\tilde\Omega$ coincide" ...

Comment: I believe you are talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element#Relation_to_the_Laplacian_on_G

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't know, since I'm not familiar with the concepts described there. I guess the situation here is more elementary.

Comment: @0xbadf00d What I am saying is that the linked-to article probably asks the correct form of your question...