# Isometric domains are isospectral for the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, laplacian, semigroup-of-operators, linear-pde

Let

- $X$ and $Y$ be separable Hilbert spaces;
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be orthonormal bases of $X$ and $Y$, respectively;
- $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$
- $$S(t)x:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_Xe_n\;\;\;\text{for }x\in X\text{ and }t\ge0$$ and $$T(t)y:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\mu_nt}\langle y,f_n\rangle_Hf_n\;\;\;\text{for }y\in Y\text{ and }t\ge0$$

We can easily show that $(S(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a contractive $C^0$-semigroup on $X$ with generator $$Ax:=-\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle_Xe_n\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathcal D(A):=\left\{x\in X:\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n^2\lambda_n^2\left|\langle x,e_n\rangle_X\right|^2<\infty\right\}$$ and the same clearly applies to $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ (let $B$ denote its generator).

> I want to know when we can find an unitary $U\in\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ such that $$\forall t>0:US(t)=T(t)U\tag1.$$ Since I'm not sure how specific this question is, the particular situation I'm interested in is $X=L^2(\Omega)$ and $Y=L^2(\tilde\Omega)$, where $\Omega,\tilde\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ are bounded and open such that there is an isometry $\iota:\Omega\to\tilde\Omega$, and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are the orthonormal bases consisting of eigenvectors of $-\Delta$ on $\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega):\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)\}$ and $\{u\in H_0^1(\tilde\Omega):\Delta u\in L^2(\tilde\Omega)\}$, respectively, and the sequences $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

Unless, I'm missing something, we should be always to find an unitary $U\in\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ with $Ue_n=f_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. This should simply follow from the fact that $V:X\to\ell^2(I),x\mapsto(\langle x,e_i\rangle)_{i\in I}$ and $W:Y\to\ell^2(I),y\mapsto(\langle y,f_i\rangle)_{i\in I}$ are unitary isomorphisms so that we can take $U:=W^{-1}\circ V$. However, in generality I'm not able to deduce $(1)$ from that (using this particular $U$.)

In the particular case of the Laplacian, we could consider $Uf:=f\circ\iota^{-1}$ for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, which is clearly unitary and hence maps ortrhonormal bases to orthonormal bases. But, again, I'm not able to show $(1)$ for this choice of $U$ either ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be motivated by the "Can you here the shape of a drum" question.

First, let me briefly give a general answer to the question and then explain how it is related to the specific setting of Laplace operators.

**General situation.**

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two Hilbert spaces and let $A_1: H_1 \supseteq D(A_1) \to H_1$ and $A_2: H_2 \supseteq D(A_2) \to H_2$ be self-adjoint operators with compact resolvent which have finite spectral bound and thus generate $C_0$-semigroups $T_1$ and $T_2$.

**Proposition 1.**
The following assertions are equivalent:

(i) The operators $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the same eigenvalues, including multiplicities - i.e., they are *isospectral*.

(ii) There exists a unitary operator $U: H_1 \to H_2$ that intertwines $A_1$ and $A_2$ (equivalently, that intertwines the semigroups $T_1$ and $T_2$).

(iii) There exists a bounded linear bijection $U: H_1 \to H_2$ that intertwines $A_1$ and $A_2$ (equivalently, that intertwines the semigroups $T_1$ and $T_2$).

*Sketch of proof.*
"(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" Let $(\lambda_n)$ denote the sequence of eigenvalues of both $A_1$ and $A_2$, and let $(e_n)$ and $(f_n)$ be corresponding ONBs of eigenvectors.
Define $Ue_n := f_n$ for each $n$. Then $U$ is a unitary that intertwines $A_1$ and $A_2$.

"(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)" Obvious.

"(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)" The fact that $U$ intertwines both operators means precisely that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are *similar*; hence, they have the same eigenvalues. $\square$

**The Laplace operator**

Now we specialize to the situation where $H_1 = L^2(\Omega_1)$ and $H_2 = L^2(\Omega_2)$ for two bounded domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, und where $A_1$ and $A_2$ denote the Dirichlet Laplace operators on both spaces.

**Proposition 2.** If there is a Euclidean isometric $\iota: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ which maps $\Omega_2$ to $\Omega_1$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are isospectral.

*Sketch of proof.* Such a $\iota$ is a composition of a translation and a rotation. Hence, the mapping $U: f \mapsto f \circ \iota$ commutes with the distributional Laplace operator. Moreover, the same mapping maps $H^1_0(\Omega_1)$ to $H^1_0(\Omega_2)$, so it actually intertwines the operators $A_1$ and $A_2$. Hence, isospectrality follows from the implication "(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)" in Proposition 1. $\square$

Note that the proof of Proposition 2 has nothing to do with the converse implication "(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" in Proposition 1, i.e., the unitary $U$ in the proof of Proposition 2 is constructed by a very different method than the one in the proof of the implication "(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" in Proposition 1. (But, of course, one can show *a posteriori* that the unitary $U$ from Proposition 2 maps each eigenspace of $A_1$ to the corresponding eigenspace - for the same eigenvalue - of $A_2$).

**Hearing the shape of a drum.**

This is a famous problem, made popular by Kac, which asks under which circumstances the converse to Proposition 2 holds. I.e., assume that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are isospectral - does it follows that $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ they are congruent?

In full generality, the answer has been known to be "no" for a long time. In certain special cases, the answer is known to be "yes".

But for large classes of domains, the problem is still open.

**Isothermal drums.**

If we are interested in the "Can you here the shape of a drum" problem, why should we care about the implication "(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" in Proposition 1?

Here is an intuitive reason: Assume that $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are "good" (for instance, have $C^\infty$-boundary) and that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are isospectral - then Proposition 1 tells us that there exists an operator $U$ as in (ii) (or (iii)). If we could prove that $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are congruent, we would have a positive answer to Kac's problem - but as mentioned above, this is open.

Now assume, however, that the intertwining operator $U$ does not only exists but can be chosen such that both $U$ and $U^{-1}$ are positive (in the sense of Banach lattice, i.e., $Uf \ge 0$ iff $f \ge 0$). Then it can indeed be shown that $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are congruent; see [this paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1099.35164). Hence, we don't have a solution to Kac's problem, but we have a positive result under additional assumptions on $U$.

(*Notational remark:* If $U$ and $U^{-1}$ can be chosen to be positive, it is tempting to call $A_1$ and $A_2$ *isothermal* rather than only *isospectral* - thus the title of this little subsection here.)